# 3D cohen-sutherland clliping algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I would like to know what is the right way to convert the known 2d algorithm into a 3d algorithm.
Thanks!

Comment: Add two bits to the outcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up
"cohen-sutherland 3d clipping".

You will get a number of hits.

This is one:

//www.cs.drexel.edu/~david/Classes/CS430/Lectures/L-14_Color.6.pdf